# Notation for subset of a set $A$ that is disjoint with every other set but $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have found myself making my own notation when considering several sets, say $A,B,C,D,E$, and wanting to denote for example the set $A^{\triangle} = \{x: x\in A \land x\notin Y, Y\neq X\}$. I know when considering just two sets like $A$ and $B$ I could write the somewhat more inconvenient $A\setminus B$, but I don't know how to conveniently write this when considering several sets. Is there a simple notation for $A^{\triangle}$?

edit: Maybe I expressed myself unclearly. Although I appreciate the help, I don't consider $A\setminus(B\cup C \cup D \cup E)$ a *simple* way of writing $A^{\triangle}$. It becomes very unpractical when having to write it over and over again, not to speak of when considering more sets than five. I'm looking for something similar to $A^\triangle$, preferably just one small extra symbol denoting the set. Similar to how $\bar{A}$ can denote the complement of $A$. Again, sorry for not making this clear enough.

Comment: Would $A \setminus (B \cup C \cup D \cup E)$ work?

Comment: @EvanChen I'm afraid I expressed myself a bit unlcearly, I don't find that notation simple or convenient. I thought it was clear by me bringing up the example $A\setminus B$. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out that $x \in A^△\Leftrightarrow (x \in A ∧x \notin B ∧x \notin C∧x \notin D∧x \notin E)$.

Hence, by de Morgan law, $$x \in A^△\Leftrightarrow (x \in A ∧\neg (x \in B \vee x \in C\vee x \in D\vee x \in E))$$$$\Leftrightarrow (x \in A ∧\neg (x \in B\cup C\cup D \cup E ))$$$$\Leftrightarrow (x \in A\setminus( B\cup C\cup D \cup E ))$$

Therefore, $A\setminus( B\cup C\cup D \cup E )$ is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

We have already standard notations of difference and union that cover your wanted new notation.

If your set is only non-disjoint with $A$ and disjoint with some family of sets $F$ we could do some shortcuts and write (if B is designation of that set) that as $(B \cap A \neq \emptyset) \land (B \cap (\bigcup F) = \emptyset) $

We could write that also as $\displaystyle \bigcap_B (A,F)=( \supset \emptyset , = \emptyset) $